# Ruby Telnet Lib - Weird Response

Tags: ruby, telnet

I am trying to execute cmds on a remote CPU through telnet.  While some commands sent (through Ruby's stdlib for telnet) are successful, others are giving me a weird response:

> *===============================================================
>   Welcome to Microsoft Telnet Server.
>   *===============================================================
>   C:\Documents and Settings\UserJW>ls
>   Desktop
>   Favorites
>   My Documents
>   Start Menu
>   Sti_Trace.log
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\UserJW>cd\
>   More?

Why is telnet giving me this "More?" response, as if expecting something?

In the code, I am simply connecting to remote CPU, logging in, and sending commands:

```
@connection = Net::Telnet.new(...)  
@connection.login( user, pwd )  
@connection.cmd(...)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
J

**EDIT:

`@connection = Net::Telnet.new(

"Host" => machine,

"Prompt" => /[A-Za-z]:\\.*>\z/n,

"Timeout" => 3,

"Output_log" => output )

@connection.login( user, pwd )

@connection.cmd( 'ls' )

@connection.cmd( 'ls' )`

output...

> C:\Documents and Settings\UserJW>
>   ls
>   Desktop
>   Favorites
>   My Documents
>   Start Menu
>   Sti_Trace.log
>   C:\Documents and Settings\UserJW>
>   ls
>   More?

I can't even send more than one command, apparently. Is my Prompt regex wrong? I'm trying to allow..

C:[anything...]>

Comment: Please show the full text of the commands you are sending, except for any usernames and passwords obviously.

Comment: that last backslash typically means "there's more on the next line" I believe...

Comment: Did you very get a response to this? I'm running into the same issue. Ready to ditch Ruby for Python.

Answer (score 0):

I meet a same problem with you ( [ruby telnet to windows 2008 ,execute command error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16410550/ruby-telnet-to-windows-2008-execute-command-error) ).I solved it. the reason is ruby net/telnet library use error newline seperator. Must be EOL(CR+LF) but CR+NULL . But I don't know who make the bug,windows or ruby? I write a monkey patch as below:

```
class Net::Telnet
    def print(string)
      string = string.gsub(/#{IAC}/no, IAC + IAC) if @options["Telnetmode"]

      if @options["Binmode"]
        self.write(string)
      else
        if @telnet_option["BINARY"] and @telnet_option["SGA"]
          self.write(string.gsub(/\n/n, CR))
        elsif @telnet_option["SGA"]
          self.write(string.gsub(/\n/n, EOL)) ### fix here. reaplce CR+NULL bY EOL
        else
          self.write(string.gsub(/\n/n, EOL))
        end
      end
    end
end
```